# Как сделать, чтобы каждая запись открывалась отдельно?

Tags: get, php, mysql

Вот написал скрипт, который выводит записи из БД MySQL. Файл index.php :

```
<?php
    $host="localhost"; 
    $user="root"; 
    $pwd="123456"; 
    $db=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pwd); 
    mysql_select_db("test",$db);

    $result=mysql_query('SELECT id,date,quote FROM quotes where approved = 1 ORDER by id DESC'); 
    $n=mysql_num_rows($result); 
    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) echo 'ID записи: '.mysql_result($result,$i,'id').', дата: '.mysql_result($result,$i,'date').', текст:<br> '.mysql_result($result,$i,'quote').'<br> <br>';
    ?>
```

Странца с этим  скриптом будет выглядеть вот так:

```
ID записи: 2, дата: 2012-06-01 15:57:49, текст:
test test

ID записи: 1, дата: 2012-06-01 14:04:21, текст:
test
```

Помогите мне сделать, чтобы каждая запись открывалась отдельно. Т.е.

```
ID записи: 2, дата: 2012-06-01 15:57:49, текст:
test test (тут гиперссылка, где будет размещена запись с ID 2)

ID записи: 1, дата: 2012-06-01 15:57:49, текст:
test (тут гиперссылка, где будет размещена запись с ID 1)
```

Т.е. чтобы можно было открывать file.php?id=2, например. Думаю, что смысл ясен. Помогите, пожалуйста. С меня жирный плюсик :)

Comment: Кто такие умные: минусовать умеют, а мозгов нет. Школьники? Тут есть true кодеры, которые смогут помочь новичку?

Answer (score 2):

вкратце так получаем запись по id и выводим

```
<?php
$result=mysql_query('SELECT id,date,quote FROM quotes where approved = 1 AND id='.intval($_GET['id']).' ORDER by id DESC');
    $a = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo 'ID записи: '.$a[0]['id'].', дата: '.$a[0]['date'].', текст:<br> '.$a[0]['quote'].'<br> <br>';
```

если нужна ссылка на следующую запись, то примерно то же, только меняется запрос

```
<?php
$result=mysql_query('SELECT id,date,quote FROM quotes where approved = 1 AND id>'.intval($_GET['id']).' ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1');
```

ссылку, уж как нибудь сами, идею подсказал.